# Where's the 'Edit my profile' button gone?

Tags: support, profile-page, login, user-accounts

I clearly remember that when on a PC I would go to `my profile page > Edit Profile and Settings`  and there I could change stuff like my login settings and alike.

Now I got to my profile and all I see is my picture and an option to copy data from my other profiles on the various SE communities. What's going on?

(I specifically want to delete my profile picture, change password and change login associations).

Comment: (*[‘Is gone’ vs. ‘has gone’ in English](https://jakubmarian.com/is-gone-vs-has-gone-in-english/)* (changes are ***not*** (necessarily) implied).)

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this on any site. For me, the "Edit Profile and Settings" heading, link, and page exist on any site where I've checked. While I only checked a few sites, I did check all the localized SO sites, here on MSE, and a few others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the per-site-metas there are reduced options available in [your **meta** profile editor](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) (English.SE) compared to [your **main** profile editor](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) (English.SE). From the description in your question it sounds like you are using the [Stack Exchange profile editor](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) (Network Profile) which only offers the "Update profile info" option.

To use a more fully featured editor go to one of [your **main** sites](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts), click on your avatar (on the top bar), and choose: "Edit profile and settings".